# Date field defaults are not shown as values

Tags: datetime

I have added the date field in the user profile where in i have made the setting as bellow the default value is **NOW** [it should show the current date], and also the end date default value selected as **Relative**,and chosen +11 months but when i go and check in the user create page the date field does't showing current date also the end date which has been set to 11 months, please can any one tell me why this is ?it will be great helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But does it work without an end date?

Comment: @leymannx: no its not working, i dont know why its happening i am completely stuck i am trying to figure it out but no use.please if any reason for this cause let me know.

Comment: Normally this only takes effect when you create a new user or resave an existing user. Can you try both please?

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: @leymannx: i  was trying to edit the user so the end date of date field was not showing.